# Flexbox working differently on safari compared to chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I have here a rather frustrating scenario where my font "History Maps" centres within its title box on chrome using flexbox, but does not at all within the safari browser. Please see: http://www.historymaps2.drcrittall.com/welcome.php

Here is the html and CSS:

```css
 /* Parent elements */ 
    html,body {
    
     height:100%;
    }
    
    /* Sets the container-fluid, row and column classes to 100% of the html and body elements */ 
    .container-fluid,.row, .col-md-6, .col-xs-10 {
     height:100%;
    }
    
    
    
    #titleframe {
    
     position:relative;
     display:-webkit-box;
     display:-ms-flexbox;
     display:flex;/* Flex-box ensures font is centered both vertically and horizontally within the title frame using align-items and justify-content. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block */
        -webkit-box-align:center;
        -ms-flex-align:center;
        align-items:center;
        -webkit-box-pack:center;
        -ms-flex-pack:center;
        justify-content:center;  
        max-width:100%; /* max-width ensures background does not stretch outside container div */ 
        height:15%;   /* Represents height relative to parent elements - in this case .container-fluid,.row, .col-md-6, .col-xs-10 which are all set to 100% */  
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:2px;
        border-color:black;
        
        background: url("../img/pages/frame4.3.jpg");
        background-size: 100% 100%; /* Sets background image to fill 100% of container in both x and y directions. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160764/background-image-stretch-y-axis-only-keep-repeat-x */
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        
    }
    
    #titlepaper {
    
        position:absolute;    
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        right:0px;
        bottom:0px;    
        width:100%; 
        height:100%; 
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:2px;
        border-color:black;
        /*padding:12px 25px;*/
        padding: 2% 5.5% 2% 5%; 
        
    }
    
    #maintitle {
    
        position:absolute;   
        font-family:"Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
        font-style:italic;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: black;
        text-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #b2a98f,
                     0px 14px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
                     0px 24px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                     0px 34px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        
        word-wrap:break-word;   
        font-size:50px; 
        width:500px;
        text-align: center;
        flex:1; 
     
    
    }
    
    /* All media break-points: https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints */
    @media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    
     
     
     
     /* Styles */
     #maintitle {
     
      font-size:30px;
      
      width:200px; 
       
     
     }
     
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en">

    <head>
 
        <!-- http://getbootstrap.com/ -->
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
  <meta charset = "utf-8"> 
  
  <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  
        <link href="/css/welcome.css?parameter=2" rel="stylesheet"/>
        
        <title>History Maps</title>

        <!-- https://jquery.com/ -->
        <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

        <!-- http://getbootstrap.com/ -->
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    
    <body>
    
     <div class = "container-fluid" style = "border:solid;">
      
      <div class = "row" style = "margin-top:5%">
       <div class = "col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10" >
        <!--
        <img id = "titleframe" src="../img/pages/frame4.3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" style = "height:auto; max-width:100%;">
        
        <img id ="titlepaper" src="img/pages/paper.jpg" class="img-fluid">-->
        <div id = "titleframe">
         <img id ="titlepaper" class = "img-fluid" src="img/pages/paper.jpg">
         <font id="maintitle">History Maps</font>     
        </div>
        <!--<div class = "container-fluid" id = "test"></div>-->
                
       </div> 
      
      </div>
      
     </div>
    
    </body>
    
</html>
```

If anyone can see why the font-centring behaves so differently on Chrome to Safari I would be most grateful to know why.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either removing `position: absolute;` from `#maintitle` or changing it to `relative`.

```css
/* Parent elements */ 
html,body {

    height:100%;
}

/* Sets the container-fluid, row and column classes to 100% of the html and body elements */ 
.container-fluid,.row, .col-md-6, .col-xs-10 {
    height:100%;
}



#titleframe {

    position:relative;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;/* Flex-box ensures font is centered both vertically and horizontally within the title frame using align-items and justify-content. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block */
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    align-items:center;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    justify-content:center;  
    max-width:100%; /* max-width ensures background does not stretch outside container div */ 
    height:15%;   /* Represents height relative to parent elements - in this case .container-fluid,.row, .col-md-6, .col-xs-10 which are all set to 100% */  
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:black;

    background: url("../img/pages/frame4.3.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%; /* Sets background image to fill 100% of container in both x and y directions. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160764/background-image-stretch-y-axis-only-keep-repeat-x */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}

#titlepaper {

    position:absolute;    
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;    
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:black;
    /*padding:12px 25px;*/
    padding: 2% 5.5% 2% 5%; 

}

#maintitle {

    position:relative;   
    font-family:"Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #b2a98f,
                 0px 14px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
                 0px 24px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 0px 34px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

    word-wrap:break-word;   
    font-size:50px; 
    width:500px;
    text-align: center;
    flex:1;
}

/* All media break-points: https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints */
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) {




    /* Styles */
    #maintitle {

        font-size:30px;

        width:200px; 


    }

}
```

```html
<div class = "container-fluid" style = "border:solid;">

        <div class = "row" style = "margin-top:5%">
            <div class = "col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10" >
                <!--
                <img id = "titleframe" src="../img/pages/frame4.3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" style = "height:auto; max-width:100%;">

                <img id ="titlepaper" src="img/pages/paper.jpg" class="img-fluid">-->
                <div id = "titleframe">
                    <img id ="titlepaper" class = "img-fluid" src="img/pages/paper.jpg">
                    <font id="maintitle">History Maps</font>                
                </div>
                <!--<div class = "container-fluid" id = "test"></div>-->

            </div> 

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, changing #maintitle to position:relative did the job. Why does this fix the problem?

Comment: Because titlepaper is also absolute, so you had a conflict between those 2 absolutes (titlepaper & maintitle) nested inside a relative (titleframe), considering the image exceeds it's relative parent width, it pushed the text out as well, so setting relative will maintain relation with it's parent width and avoid being pushed by the other absolute before (titlepaper).